# PHP FTP менеджер

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

Задача такая, нужен простой ftp менеджер, который будет контектиться с сервером по заданным параметрам.

Желательно без авторизации, чтобы параметры прописывались в конфиге. В дальнейшем это будет интегрироваться в сайт на WP где параметры подключения будут браться из настроек

Comment: под менеджером вы понимаете FTP-клиент?

Comment: я так понимаю, вам деплой нужен? тогда можно посмотреть на [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), написано на питоне, позволяет выполнять различные команды на удаленном сервере, т.е. неплохо подходит для автоматизации. Для самого wp я бы посоветовал [это](http://wp-cli.org/), позволяет выполнять различные действия из командной строки. В связке можно получить неплохой инструмент. Вместо fabric можно использовать и другое: [mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/), [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/), [phing](https://www.phing.info/), [deployer](http://deployer.org/) и другие.

Answer (score 1):

Linux? Windows?

---

Если linux, то удобно использовать lftp (Его можно хоть php_exec -ом запускать). Сам использую для переброски бэкапа с одного из хостов.

А если передача файлов с linux на linux, я бы предложил использовать scp.
Гораздо удобнее.

Если windows - то winscp. Умеет работать со скриптами. Т.е. можно задать логины/ пароли, выполняемые действия и т.д.